# Sprites drawing over text in unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am trying to display the score for my game, however, my background sprite is drawing right over it. I have tried assigning some type of layer tag but I can't find one for text. Everything I try, the text is always hidden under the sprite for my background (and any other sprite for that matter). Is there a way to assign the text to be drawn over everything, I have tried looking at tons of sites in hopes of a fix but I can't seem to find anything. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hierarchy creation menu, pick UI->Text
This will add you 3 Elements to the hierarchy: Canvas, and 2 child gameobjects which are Text and EventManager. These are all needed for the proccess.

The text gameobject is part of the UI system Unity has, means that if done correctly, it should show over all sprites.
Programmatically you can change text by simply saying:

```
myUItext.text = "Text that will show on UI!"
```

Manually you can change position, font and text using the hierarchy view.

For further details use this video [from the official Unity tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/projects)